# Database: AOC (intersection-based) efficient 3-way join?

Tags: database

I am attempting to improve performance on a highly normalized database wherein I have the following structure.

`entity (identity)
org (identity)
entity-org relation (many to many)
org-entity-owner-relation (many to many + column-informed state)
vuln (identity)
entity-vuln (identity-identity relation 1)`

My issue is with the 3-way identity relationship wherein the relationship between **entity-vuln** relation intersection becomes a **subquery** of relation between the **unrelated org-to-vuln relationship**.

If there is an intersection between **entity** and **vuln** and there is a relationship between **entity** and **org** then I need to be able to show a list and count of **org-entity-vuln relation** and **org-vuln-entity relation**.  My issue is with sorting and re-indexing.

Is there a way to leverage the database for this effectively or must I do my set operations locally in code?